# Syncing data and images with a client in a web application

Tags: php, synchronization, local-storage

I'm writing a web application in PHP which needs to store images and image meta data. In future, the application may need to work offline on the client. A user might need to download all the images and data to his laptop before going to a remote area without internet access. Whilst at the remote location the user could add new images to the system and be able to compare them with his local copy of the image database. When returning to an area with internet access, the user would run a sync operation which would copy his new images to the server and retrieve any new ones.

I've looked at the new web storage / localstorage options in HTML5 (web sql database seems to have been dropped) and I think this is going to be too limited as there is only 5MB space and one or two images could easily exceed that.

Is what I want to do actually possible / practical with a browser-based web application? Or should I be looking at writing a desktop/tablet application with local file storage capabilities for users without net access. Initially, it does need to be a web application, I'm just trying to think ahead. Will I give myself more options in future by using something like couchDB for the backend from the start? As I understand it, this comes with good syncing functionality.

Thanks,

Comment: you can't have php running on the localmachine if they don't have it installed, and even then it wouldn't be such a great idea because you would have to make the entire source code available for the user. What you should do is make a desktop application written in w/e language you might prefer, i recommend python it has some similarities with php therefore a good starting point. you could save every data in a local xml file don't need a database. And then post everything to a php site once internet is available

Comment: You will have to have something running on the users' computers with local disk access, be it a java applet in the images folder, or better yet a dedicated desktop app in any language you want for the syncing. It could just be a wrapper around rsync.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I may use Titanium desktop as it has local sqlite and file system access. Wunderlist has done this (mostly) successfully. I'm not really up for learning a desktop language at this stage, though I do know some Objective-C

Comment: I would also avoid storing the images directly in the DB. Store them in the filesystem and keep a reference in the DB only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use Titanium Desktop.

http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/